# Linking click issue with the backbone JS frame work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a very weird problem happening in my application. I am using backbone JS framework as well as loading the screens one depending on another. To explain my problem below is the example of URL formation, the screens are loading and URL is getting formed one by one. But when I directly create the same URL & hit into the browser the screens are not getting loaded. I needed this as we want to link one screen to another

For example:
First, the parent is loading depending on parent id, children are loading, depending on children grandchildren are loading.

So below is URL formation.

```
https://example.com/#/parent-detail/xxx?child1=xxx&child2=xxx&child3=xxxxxxx&child4=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

In the above URL each child id depending on one another.

When I want to link the last child using this URL, then this is not going through that particular page.

But when I go with to the page by clicking one by one to each child then it's loading the respected child page.

Please help me out how should I link the last grandchild using the URL.

I am using below technical stack:

```
Backbone JS & Javascript - For Frontend
Node JS - for backend
Mysql - database
MongoDB -  database
Redis server - caching
HTML5 & CSS3 - design
```

**EDIT**

Here is how I am forming the URL on my frontend pages **dahboard.html**:

```
<a href="#/parent-detail_2/<%= child[0].parent_id %>?s=<%= child[0].child1 %>&child2=<%= child[0].child2 %>&child3=<%= child[0]._id %>"><span></span> <b><%= child[i].child[0].name %></b></a>
```

This URL is getting formed with above code that I am using in the dashboard.

Here are my application routes from **routes.js**:

```
 routes:{

        "dashboard"                                     : "dashboard",
        "dashboard/parent/:id"                           : "dashboard_parent",
        "signup"                                        : "signup",
        "forgotpassword"                                : "forgotpassword",
        "change-password/:token"                        : "resetpassword",
        "login"                                         : "login", 
        "logout"                                        : "logout",
        "parents/"                                       : "parents",
        "parent-detail/:id"                              : "parent_detail",
        "parent-detail_1/:id"                            : "parent_detail_1",
        "parent-detail_2/:id"                            : "parent_detail_2",
        "verify_user/:token"                            : "verifyEmail"
}
```

**Here is the carter code:**

```
window.ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#content2",
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        // $('body').attr('class', 'fixed-topbar fixed-sidebar theme-sdtl color-default dashboard');

        $.get(BASEURL + "template/parents/parents.html", function(html) {
            var template = _.template(html);
            var vars = {username: window.localStorage.getItem('username') };
            html = template(vars);
            self.$el.html(html);
        });
    },

});

var ParentTabsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#parents-tabs',
    props: {},

    initialize: function(params) {
        // console.log(params);
        if(params && params.sharedParentModel) {
            this.sharedParentModel = params.sharedParentModel
        }
        //console.log(this.sharedParentModel);
    },
    renderChat: function(parent) {
        var _this = this;
        $.get(BASEURL + "template/parents/right_section/chat.html", function(html) {
            $(parent).html(html);
        });
    },
    renderTasks: function(parent, activity_id) {
        this.sharedParentModel.activity_id = activity_id;
        var _this = this;
        $.get(BASEURL + "template/parents/right_section/tasks_layout.html", function(html) {
            var template = _.template(html);
            $(parent).html(template());
        }).done(function() {
            new TasksView({sharedParentModel: _this.sharedParentModel}).load_data_and_render();
        });
    },
    renderInvitePeople: function(parent) {
        this.clearIt(parent);
        $(parent).append(new InvitePeopleView({sharedParentModel: this.sharedParentModel}).render().el);
    },
    renderShowInvitedPeople: function(parent) {
        this.clearIt(parent);
        $(parent).append(new ShowInvitedPeopleView({sharedParentModel: this.sharedParentModel}).render().el);
    },
    renderTeam: function(parent) {
        var _this = this;
        // console.log(this.sharedParentModel);

        this.clearIt(parent);
        $(parent).append(new TeamListParentView({sharedParentModel: this.sharedParentModel}).render().el);
    },
    renderTasksInfoChat: function(parent) {
        this.clearIt(parent);

        var outerTemplate = crel('div', {class: 'row'});
        var promiseOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.get(BASEURL + "template/parents/right_section/task_info.html")
                .done(function(html) { resolve(html); })
                .fail(function(err) { reject(err)});
        });
        var promiseTwo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.get(BASEURL + "template/parents/right_section/chat.html")
                .done(function(html) { resolve(html); })
                .fail(function(err) { reject(err); });
        });

        Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo]).then(function(values) { 
            var view = _.map(values, function(dom) { $(outerTemplate).append(dom); });
            $(parent).append(outerTemplate);
        });
    },
    clearThem: function(parents) {
        var _this = this;
        _.each(parents, function(parent) {
            $(parent).empty();
        })
    },
    clearIt: function(parent) {
        $(parent).empty();
    },
    destroy_view: function() {
        // COMPLETELY UNBIND THE VIEW
        this.undelegateEvents();
        this.$el.removeData().unbind(); 
        // Remove view from DOM
        this.remove();  
        Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
    },
    set_params: function(params) {
        if(params && params.sharedParentModel) {
            this.sharedParentModel = params.sharedParentModel
        }
    },
});
```

What is wrong here.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nice that's you're using a such a stack. However, we really don't need all that detail for the question being asked, nor is it appropriate to "spam" all those tags onto your question which is seemingly solely about a "front end design" concept. Despite someone's wayward vote here, this is NOT a good question. The best way to ask "What is wrong here". Is [to give people enough code to reproduce the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So we don't need to see all those backend things unless you actually include backend code that is relevant to those services. Hope that's clear

Comment: Yes sure, let me edit the question and include the backend code.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. **We don't want the backend** unless it's absolutely relevant to the question being asked. From what I can gather, it's NOT. The relevant code missing rather is "front end code". Also really obtuse and obscure questions which receive votes immediately on posting get noticed, and not in a good way. You might consider that as well.

Comment: Yes, I considered that I will put all the relevant code here with which I am facing the issue. Just adding that for both the side. So that it would be more clear.

Comment: typo in your route: `paent-detail`... You need also a route to cater for any query strings, where's the code for that?

Comment: @Stuart added carter code and updated the type from the routes. Please help.

Comment: Where/how are you creating the views?

Comment: For respected views, there are templates in the backbone js. So for my dashboard view, there are two files dashboard.js & dashboard.html which is routed from backbone routes.

Answer (score 0):

So basically we have found a workaround for our problem. We have loaded the last child in the parent views that was not loading directly. So for that loaded each child by setting the click trigger with some interval using below code.

```
renderChild:function(e){
    var child_id = $(e.target).closest('.renderChild').attr('child-id');
    var renderChildTimer = setInterval(function(){
        if (document.getElementById(task_id)) {
           $('#'+child_id).trigger('click');
           clearInterval(renderChildTimer);
        }
    }, 800);    
}
```

Here in above code we have triggered each child id from url with click function.